# jquery - How to add items recursively within one another

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = '<div> A div within a div </div>';
        $("#div1").append(element).append(element1);
    });
```

I am trying to add a `div` **within another** `div` dynamically. But the append method returns the selector in this case it is `#div`. And the elements are added one after another and not within one another. Thats not what I want I want one div to go within a div like the following-:

```
<div> A div within a div 
       <div> A div within a div 
              <div> A div within a div 
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use a reference to the last element added because I may like to do the above nesting of `div`s for a large number of times example 50.

Is there a jquery function which returns the last element added ? I searched but jquery seems to be lacking the feature of returning the last element added. All the jquery selectors return the selector itself and not the element added.

Comment: Do you mean fifty divs inside each other? Or fifty divs next to each other?

Comment: @Louy 50 divs within each other. One div within and another div.

Comment: Use `:last` as suggested in my answer. Merely 1 line from there.

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/johnjacob/4esu5y1o/1/ Can't get any better.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep What if there are other divs on the page?

Comment: ads a unique `id` to the `div` that he wants to select initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to nest your method calls:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element1 = '<div> A div within a div </div>';
  $("#div1").append(
    $(element1).append(
      $(element1).append(element1)
    )
  );
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

For deep nesting, take advantage of functions:

```js
function nestDeep(count) {
  var el = $('<div> A div within a div </div>');
  return count > 0 
    ? el.append(nestDeep(count - 1)) 
    : el;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#div1").append(nestDeep(50));
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Of course, if you absolutely must have this method that you are describing, you can always add it yourself:

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.appendR = function(toAppend) {
    var $toAppend = $(toAppend);
    this.append($toAppend);
    return $toAppend;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var element1 = '<div> A div within a div </div>';
  var element2 = '<div> Another div within a div </div>';
  $("#div1").appendR(element1).appendR(element2);
});
```

```css
div  {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Gonna get ugly fast if this goes 50 levels deep like the OP suggests.

Comment: @j08691 True, but any handwritten code would be ugly for 50 levels of nesting. The function OP is supposedly seeking wouldn't prevent that. That's what functions are for. :)

Comment: @JLRishe  Exactly its going to get ugly as the number of increase. That's why I wanted if there was a way to return the last element added. Also won't adding to `$(element1)` just add element to the same div rather than adding one div within the other ?

Comment: @Heidi You are trying to solve the wrong problem. The problem is that you are trying to handwrite 50 levels of nesting instead of writing elegant code. And to answer your question, no, since `element1` is a string in this example, every occurrence of `$(element1)` will create a new div.

Answer (score 1):

Nice and easy way using `:last` and `.append`:

```
function div(times) {
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        $('div:last').append('<div> A div within a div</div>');
    }
}
div(50);
```

`div:last` selects the last element `div`. Hence,it will recursively, nest itself. 
http://jsfiddle.net/johnjacob/4esu5y1o/1/

Comment: Can you precisely explain what the `last` property does and how your code works ?

Comment: Edited. You can look up at docs for that function for more details.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var el = $('<div> A div within a div </div>').appendTo('#div1');
for( var i = 1; i < 50; ++ i ) {
    el = el.clone().appendTo(el);
}
```

Comment: What if each div was different ? Is there really no way that jquery can return the last added child ?

Comment: That is precisely what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid recursion as much as possible. In this case you can simply use normal for loop because we know exactly the number of times, something like this:

```
function nestDivs(e, n){
  var div = $("#div1");
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    var appendee = $(e);
    div.append(appendee);
    div = appendee;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = '<div> A div within a div </div>';
  nestDivs(element, 10);//10 times
});
```

As another answer suggested, maybe using `appendTo` will shorten the code.

Comment: This works if all the divs are exactly the same but what happens if each div is different. Suppose they all would have different inline css ?

Comment: @Heidi that means you have to prepare all the divs beforehand (or at least some mechanism to map the CSS with each one). I guess you could loop through all the prepared divs instead.

Comment: @Heidi Why would they have inline CSS at all?

Comment: @JLRishe What I am trying to say if some of the divs where different from the other ones, what would I do then. It would be great if I had something like -:
`$("#div1").append(div1)
.append(div2)
.append(div3);`

Where each div would go within the other.

Comment: @Heidi you may have to put all your divs such as in some array, refer them using index (of the for loop), ...

Comment: @Heidi I have a strong feeling that this is an artificial problem with a much better solution than the one you are envisioning (but you have not given us enough detail to guide you toward a better solution). However, if you absolutely must have this method that you describe, please see the edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: @JLRishe I am trying to create chat-popups like the one in Facbook. So I each chat popup is a set of divs that are added within one another. Thats why I was looking to return the last appended child.

Comment: @Heidi In that case, I would say you should split your logic out into smaller functions that build the individual parts and assemble them together by calling other functions to build the sub-parts. That's how cleanly structured code is written. Trying to build the entire chat popup in a giant mass of code is the wrong thing to do, and that's why you think you need this method.